# How do I make a command to add a variable and let the print command print the number or string of it

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
            //Print command
            string print = Console.ReadLine();
            if (print.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("print: "))
            {
                string p2 = print.Substring(print.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(p2);
            }

            string var = Console.ReadLine();
            if (var.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("var "))
            {
                string v2 = var.Substring(var.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

> I want to now how I can create a var by typing var and then set a number to or a string and be able to print the number or string

Comment: `var` is a keyword.  I recommend using a different name for your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` is a keyword. Solve the problem by renaming `var` to something like `variable`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
            //Print command
            string print = Console.ReadLine();
            if (print.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("print: "))
            {
                string p2 = print.Substring(print.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(p2);
            }

            string variable = Console.ReadLine();
            if (variable.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("var "))
            {
                string v2 = variable.Substring(variable.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** New requirements, this is code I came up with but it's without error handling:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Variables
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.Clear();
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            do
            {
                //Print command
                string command = Console.ReadLine();
                if (command.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("print: "))
                {
                    string p2 = command.Substring(command.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
                    if (dict.ContainsKey(p2)) Console.WriteLine(dict[p2]);
                    else Console.WriteLine("Variable {0} undefined!");
                }
                if (command.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("var "))
                {
                    string v2 = command.Substring(command.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
                    string[] parts = v2.Split(new char[]{'='}, 2,  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    parts[0] = parts[0].Trim();
                    parts[1] = parts[1].Trim();
                    dict.Add(parts[0], int.Parse(parts[1]));
                }
            }
            while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although using a different name would be better, keywords can be 'escaped' by prefixing them with an `@` symbol, which converts them to an identifier. Thus, `@var` should work. But it looks horrible, and you're better off using a more meaningful name. One of the nice things about English is that you can always find another name for something.

Comment: Ok but, but now i want to type in the console var x = 0 then i want to type print: x and print 0, how do i do that?

Comment: Well this might be a bit trickier. You would have to store all passed in variables in a datastructure like `Dictionary<string, int>` and then parse that int from a string and append it to the Dictionary.

Comment: Ok, so how would i set that up?

Comment: Ok i looked up Dictionary and i see how i could set it up

Comment: But im a bit confused